Finding parameters for Fisher's multivariate hypergeometric distribution given means
I want an efficient-to-sample distribution over sets $S\subseteq [n] = \{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $|S|=k$ and $\Pr[i\in S]=p_i$ for some known $k,p_1,\ldots,p_n$.  A natural choice is Fisher's multivariate noncentral hypergeometric distribution, in which the elements have weights $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ and $\Pr[S]=\frac{1}{Z}\prod_{i\in S}w_i $ for some normalizing constant $Z$.
It is not too hard to compute the $p_i$'s given the $w_i$'s. I'd like to know about the inverse problem.  Given a set of $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ satisfying $\sum_i p_i = k$, can one efficiently compute some corresponding weights $w_1,\ldots,w_n$?
For example, if $n=3, k=2, p_1=p_2=3/4, p_3=1/2$ then I might choose $w_1=w_2=1$ and $w_3=1/2$.  But I don't know how to find the $\{w_i\}$ efficiently in general.
If this is too hard to do for Fisher's distribution, then I'd be happy with any other distribution over sets $S$ such that $|S|=k$, $\Pr[i\in S]=p_i$ and $\Pr[i,j\in S]\leq p_i p_j$.  I looked at Wallenius's but it seemed less tractable.
Footnote: Here's how you calculate the $p_i$'s given the $w_i$'s.  Let $f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n (1+xw_i)$.  Then $Z= [x^k]f(x)$ (meaning the coefficient of $x^k$) and $p_i = \frac{1}{Z} w_i \frac{d}{dw_i} Z$.

I couldn't relate the problem description with Fisher's multivariate noncentral hypergeometric distribution. How does it correspond to the model of "drawing $k$ balls from an urn with $N$ balls of $n$ colors"? Do you have a concrete example?

Thanks for the comment and sorry if I was vague.  Using the notation on the wikipedia page, I have $m_1=\cdots=m_c=1$, $n_{\text{mine}}=c_{\text{Wikipedia}}$, , $k_{\text{mine}}=n_{\text{Wikipedia}}$.  The key is that there is just one ball of each color, so our random choice can be thought of as a subset, not a multiset. Does that help?

Sorry, I'm being slow to understand $k$ and its relationship to $Z$.  The exponents of $x$ in $f(x)$ are always integers but it it appears that $k$ can be any positive real value up to $n$.  So if k is not an integer, then $Z=[x^k]f(x)$ would mean that $Z=0$.  Or are the $p_i$'s always chosen such that their sum is an integer?  What am I missing?

$|S|=k$ so yes we must have $\sum_i p_i = k$.  And $Z=\sum_{S : |S|=k} \prod_{i\in S} w_i$.  (This is what we need so the probability distribution defined in the first paragraph comes out normalized.) The footnote is just an efficient way to calculate this on a computer since the naive expression involves summing $\binom{n}{k}$ terms.

I added an example that hopefully clarifies what's going on.

I found a paper that addresses my question.
Weighted finite population sampling to maximize entropy
by Xiang-Hui Chen, Arthur P. Dempster and Jun S. Liu.   In Biometrika, Volume 81, Issue 3, September 1994, Pages 457–469, https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/81.3.457
They don't have a closed-form expression for the $w_i$ but they do have a rapidly convergent numerical algorithm.
